# Javascript: Which way is better to check conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, which will be better way to check conditional statement in terms of performance, robustness and which is the best practice?

```
var x = null;
// this condition is checked frequently and x will be set to null or some value accordingly
if(x !== null){...}
 OR
if(!!x){...}
```

Comment: without knowing the expected data, it is hard to decide.

Comment: Your two statements are not equivalent!

Comment: `x !== null` and `!!x` don't test the same thing. What about `x = false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do

```
if (x) { ... }
```

Simply says, if `x` is a truthy value.

As Nina pointed out. I would always add some extra validation, depending on what I'm expecting.

```
if (x && x > 0) { ... }
```

Or

```
if (x && x instanceof Array)
```

But I'm always checking x has some sort of value and isn't `undefined` or `null`

Comment: what about zero? is it valid?

Comment: @NinaScholz i wouldn't use it to check numbers. I would always add, `&& x > 0` or something similar to it

Comment: it won't fail for `x == ""` because x is a string and nothing in it is a valid string. You can always regex against strings to make sure they contain what you want

Comment: actually the question is not clear about testing values. it makes no sense to answer a question without getting a clue what to test.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah but obviously they're looking for a good approach to conditionals around nulls. I think this approach is a good approach, basic defensive coding.

Comment: Plus if we can't answer the question accurately, then maybe it is too broad and should be closed?!

Answer (score 1):

It's never necessary to write `if(!!x){...}`. That is exactly the same thing as writing `if(x){...}`. Using the `!` operator twice converts a value to a boolean that reflects whether it is "truthy" or not. But the `if` statement does that anyway: it tests whether the value you provide is "truthy". So whether you use `!!` or not it will do the same thing.

`if(x !== null){...}` is something else entirely. It doesn't just check whether `x` is "truthy", it specifically compares the value of `x` with `null`. For example, if `x` has the numeric value `0`, `if(x){...}` or `if(!!x){...}` will *not* execute the `...` code, because `0` is a "falsy" value, but `if(x!==null)` *will* execute the `...` code, because `0` is not the same value as `null`.

A related example is `if(x!=null){...}` or `if(x==null){...}`. (Note the use of `!=` or `==` instead of `!==` or `===`.) This is a bit of a special case in JavaScript. When you compare against `null` using the `!=` or `==` operator, it actually compares against either `null` or `undefined` and treats those two values the same. In other words, if `x` is *either* `null` or `undefined`, then `if(x==null){...}` will execute the `...` code, but `if(x!=null){...}` will not execute the `...` code.

It's generally recommended to avoid the `==` and `!=` operators and use the strict comparison `===` or `!==` instead, but treating `null` and `undefined` the same can be useful in some situations, so this is a case where the non-strict operators are helpful.

In any case, the real question to ask is what is the purpose of your code, and what specifically do you need to test for here?

Comment: @Biffen Good catch. I elaborated on this a bit, taking your comment into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to check for a value which is [strict inequality `!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Non-identity_strict_inequality_(!)) to `null`

> this condition is checked frequently and x will be set to null or some value  accordingly

```
if (x !== null) { /* */ }
```

Then you can only use the above comparison. Any other comparison would return a wrong result.

For example

```js
var x = 0;

if (x !== null) {                 // true
    console.log(x + ' !== null');
}

if (x) {                          // false
    console.log(x);
}

// some more checks
console.log(undefined !== null); // true
console.log(undefined != null);  // false
```

Comment: Is there a case where strict inequality would apply when comparing to null? I'd think any and all null pointers are equal and the same type. Thanks.

Comment: @JordiHernández, it is the question of `null` vs a falsey value. `null` is falsey, but not any falsey value is strict equal to `null`. that is the point here, i tried to make.

Comment: Sorry to insist but I still don't get it... Any falsey value other than null is not equal or strict equal to null. For instance, `undefined != null` should be the same as `undefined !== null` I get that if we were checking for equality, strict equality would apply, but for inequality I don't see the difference. What am I missing? Could you think of an example?

Comment: @JordiHernández, it is not the same. `undefined !== null` yields to `true`, whereas `undefined != null` yields to `false`.

Comment: I finally got it. I didn't know that comparing `undefined` to `null` would be true. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My response was quite wrong which I learned after my conversation with [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) in her own response to this thread. I updated accordingly.

There are many ways to check values depending on the type you expect to use. Therefore the problem is not so much about performance as it is with correct evaluation. Starting with your examples:

```
if(x != null)
```

This will evaluate to `false` if the value of x is either `null` or `undefined'.

The next case:

```
if(!!x)
```

This is an entirely different operation. It casts the value of x as a boolean, and in most cases `if(x)` will work the same way. But now, if the value is falsy, like 0, the empty string, the expression returns `false`. So, if expecting a number, you should check for the zero value:

```
if(x || (0 === x))
```

Bear in mind that if x were anything other than an int, the expression returns true.

And the case where you expect a string:

```
if(x || ('' === x))
```

Same thing here, if x was, say 12, the expression returns true.

I could go on with lots of examples. Unfortunately there are certain expressions that work in unexpected ways. For instance, it should be easy to check if a value is a number by calling isNaN(number), but if the value is an empty string or a representation of an array index ('[2](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_type_conversion.asp)'), isNaN returns false.

I recommend you to check [this table](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_type_conversion.asp) with all the type conversions so that you become more aware on how to check the validity of a value.